# Why won't this Java program terminate?

Tags: java, loops

so as an assignment I have to write a program that simulates dealing five cards at a time until a royal flush is dealt. It does this 10 times and then takes the average of how many times it took to deal the royal flush. I wrote a program that runs fine but doesn't account for the fact that a single deck wouldn't have two of one card, so the number of times it took to deal the royal flush was over 200,000. I think I fixed it, but now I am not getting any output because the program is not terminating. Did I unintentionally put an infinite loop?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Problem1Version2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // This program simulates the dealing of poker hands and returns the average
    // over 10 rounds of how many hands are dealt until a royal straight flush is received.

    // Initialize flush to false, which indicates that a royal straight flush has not
    // yet been dealt. Set the count variable, i, to 1.
    boolean flush = false;
    int i = 1;

    // Initialize the cards to 0 before any cards are dealt.
    int card1 = 0, card2 = 0, card3 = 0, card4 = 0, card5 = 0;

    // Initialize the total number of tries across all experiment rounds to 0.
    int totalTries = 0;

    // Repeat experiment for 10 seeds.
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

        // The round number is the seed.
        Random r = new Random(j);

        // Deal hands of 5 until a royal straight flush is dealt.
        while (flush == false) {

            // To simulate the use of one deck, only one of each card can be dealt in a hand.
            while (card1 == card2 || card1 == card3 || card1 == card4 || card1 == card5 || 
                card2 == card3 || card2 == card4 || card2 == card5 || card3 == card4 
                || card3 == card5 || card4 == card5) {

                // Cards 1-13 are the hearts, 14-26 the spades, 27-39 the clubs, and 40-52 the diamonds.
                card1 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
                card2 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
                card3 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
                card4 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
                card5 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
            }

            // Calculate the max and min of the cards.
            int max = Math.max(card1, Math.max(card2, Math.max(card3, Math.max(card4, card5))));
            int min = Math.min(card1, Math.min(card2, Math.min(card3, Math.min(card4, card5))));

            // Check if the hand dealt is a royal straight flush by confirming that 
            // they span 5 consecutive numbers (this is true if the difference between
            // the max and min is 4 since they are all different), and that they all come 
            // from the same suit (1-13, 14-26, 27-39, or 40-52).

            if (max - min == 4) {
                if ((1 <= min) && (13 >= max)) {
                    flush = true;
                }
                else if ((14 <= min) && (26 >= max)) {
                    flush = true;
                }       
                else if ((27 <= min) && (39 >= max)) {
                    flush = true;
                }       
                else if ((40 <= min) && (52 >= max)) {
                    flush = true;
                }
                else {
                    i++;    
                }
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }

        }

        // Add count from last round to total number of tries over the 10 rounds.
        totalTries += i;

        // Reset flush to false for the while loop.
        flush = false;
    }

    // Print the average number of required tries.
    System.out.println("The average number of hands it took was " + totalTries / 10.0);
}

}
```

Comment: Debug, debug and one more time debug!

Comment: I have gone line by line, and everything goes as expected. I just never find it reaching a royal flush.

Comment: Consider using enum to represent a Card and a `List<Card> deck` which can be `Collection.shuffle(deck)`.  This should simplify your code and help make debugging easier.

Comment: Thank you for that tip. Unfortunately I'm limited to what we've learned in class in the past 3 weeks, but I am sure that will be helpful down the line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following line

```
card1 = card2 = card3 = card4 = card5 = 0;
```

In the following place:

```
while (flush == false) {

    // To simulate the use of one deck, only one of each card can be
    // dealt in a hand.
    while (card1 == card2 || card1 == card3 || card1 == card4 || card1 == card5
            || card2 == card3 || card2 == card4 || card2 == card5 || card3 == card4
            || card3 == card5 || card4 == card5) {

        // Cards 1-13 are the hearts, 14-26 the spades, 27-39 the
        // clubs, and 40-52 the diamonds.
        card1 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
        card2 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
        card3 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
        card4 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
        card5 = r.nextInt(52) + 1;
    }

    // Calculate the max and min of the cards.
    int max = Math.max(card1, Math.max(card2, Math.max(card3, Math.max(card4, card5))));
    int min = Math.min(card1, Math.min(card2, Math.min(card3, Math.min(card4, card5))));

    // Check if the hand dealt is a royal straight flush by
    // confirming that
    // they span 5 consecutive numbers (this is true if the
    // difference between
    // the max and min is 4 since they are all different), and that
    // they all come
    // from the same suit (1-13, 14-26, 27-39, or 40-52).

    if (max - min == 4) {
        if ((1 <= min) && (13 >= max)) {
            flush = true;
        } else if ((14 <= min) && (26 >= max)) {
            flush = true;
        } else if ((27 <= min) && (39 >= max)) {
            flush = true;
        } else if ((40 <= min) && (52 >= max)) {
            flush = true;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        i++;
    }
    card1 = card2 = card3 = card4 = card5;
}
```

Outputting:

> The average number of hands it took was 177968.4

And note that you currently only check for straight flushes, no royal flushes. For royal flushes your inner logic should be:

```
if (max - min == 4) {
    if ((13 == max) || (26 == max) || (39 == max) || (52 == max)) {
        flush = true;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
} else {
    i++;
}
```

Outputting

> The average number of hands it took was 4944953.0

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to explain why it doesn't work when that line is one line further down, in the for loop?

Comment: @jillianjmb Because you want to deal new cards not every iteration of the for loop but ever iteration of inner while loop. Just look at the correctly indented code and think about where the values are checked for recalculation.

Comment: I see. I was initially thinking the cards would only have to be reset when flush = true, but of course they have to be reset whenever i++ occurs. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

you're not changing the values of card1, card2, card3, card4, card5 in the outer while loop.  Essentially the first time round you're going to set them to all different things (as you intend) but on every subsequent iteration they're not going to be updated with new random values because they will already meet that condition that they are all different!

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Now I see why the other program worked too - I didn't have that while loop because I wasn't checking if the cards were the same!

Comment: @jillianjmb what did you do to try to fix the problem d80 pointed out?

Comment: @luk2302 I added card1 = 0;
   card2 = 0;
   card3 = 0;
   card4 = 0;
   card5 = 0; after flush = 0;

Comment: @luk2302 also if this were the only cause, wouldn't it really just make rounds 1-9 have a count value of 1? They'd initially have the flush values, so flush would be set to true on the first time through.

Comment: Here's function that gives you a random hand of 5 cards.  Replace the inner while loop with it and it should make things a bit easier. 
`public static int [] randomHand() {
        ArrayList<Integer> allCards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=1; i<52; i++) {
            allCards.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(allCards);
        int [] hand = new int [5];
        for(int i=0; i<5; ++i){
            hand[i] = allCards.get(i);
        }
        return hand;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change value of flush to break the while loop.

Comment: As luk2302 mentioned in his answer, your code was just selecting cards once and then it was going into infinite loop.  You need to specify something to break the loop like he wrote  card1 = card2 = card3 = card4 = card5; so that fresh cards can be selected every time.

Answer (score -1):

One of your root problems is your random number generator. Did you wonder why you always end up for the same exact values on every run for all your cards? That's because the Random class is "pseudorandom" based on the initial seed that you pass in. In your code, you pass in 1 on every run, causing your cards to have the same exact values every time. To get a more "random" value, use System.currentTimeMillis() as the initial seed.

Comment: Maybe he wants to have a fixed seed so he can reproduce the outcome - anyway your answer does not come close to actually solving the problem OP is facing.